# Using "Firebase ESP8266 Client" by Mobizt: How to handle database errors?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, esp8266, arduino-ide

I'm (successfully) using the "Firebase ESP8266 Client" on my ESP8266 based Arduino project in order to read and write data to/from a Firebase realtime database.

But: From time to time, it's not possible to connect to Firebase or the database, and I've not found a way to detect that in my code. How can I detect such errors?

My current code essentially:

```c
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#include <FirebaseESP8266.h>
 
#define FIREBASE_HOST "myhost"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "myapikey"
 
FirebaseData firebaseData;
 
WiFiClientSecure client;
 
bool breakit = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  WiFi.begin("myssid", "mywpa2");             // Connect to the network
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print("myssid"); Serial.println(" ...");
 
  int i = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && !breakit) { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect
    delay(1000);
    if (i == 9) breakit = true;
    Serial.print(++i); Serial.print(' ');
  }
 
  if (!breakit) {
    Serial.println('\n');
    Serial.println("Connection established!");
    Serial.print("IP address:\t");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());         // Send the IP address of the ESP8266 to the computer
 
    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);   // how can I detect certain errors for Firebase?
    Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
    firebaseData.setBSSLBufferSize(512, 512);
    firebaseData.setResponseSize(512);
    Firebase.setMaxRetry(firebaseData, 0);
    Firebase.setTimestamp(firebaseData, "/heartbeat");
  } else {
    Serial.println('\n');
    Serial.println("Connection FAILED!");
  }
 
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Going to deepsleep ...");
  ESP.deepSleep(5 * 60 * 1000000);  // 5 minutes
}
 
void loop() {
}
```